# How do I upload the app updates in the new iTunes Connect UI

Tags: iphone, objective-c, upload, app-store-connect

I was just going to update my iPhone app. I've added the "What's New in this version" info and update everything but I can't figure out where to upload the app itself. Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to click the button on the top right of the page that says "Ready to Upload" (or something really similar). You should then be able to compile the app and upload it using the Application Loader.